# Complex case of filling NaNs in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

#### Is there a way to go from this...

```
   bloomberg  morningstar  yahoo
0  AAPL1      AAPL2        NaN
1  AAPL1      NaN          AAPL3
2  NaN        GOOG4        GOOG5
3  GOOG6      GOOG4        NaN
4  IBM7       NaN          IBM8
5  NaN        IBM9         IBM8
6  NaN        NaN          FB
```

#### ... to this ...

```
   bloomberg  morningstar  yahoo
0  AAPL1      AAPL2        AAPL3
1  GOOG6      GOOG4        GOOG5
2  IBM7       IBM9         IBM8
3  NaN        NaN          FB
```

#### ... in Pandas?

I've munged my data enough to ensure that there will never be any "conflicting" information in a given column of the starting dataframe, e.g. the following is **not** possible...

```
   A column  Another column
0  AAPL1     One thing
1  AAPL1     Another thing
```

The only thing that can happen is that any given column either has 1) no information or 2) the right information, e.g.

```
   A column  Another column
0  AAPL1     NaN
1  AAPL1     The right information
```

All I want to do is fill the NaN's with the **"right"** information where available and then drop duplicates (which should be easy).

But some NaNs should remain, as I don't have enough data to infer their value, e.g. the FB row in the example.

### Anybody have a good answer?  Thanks for the help!

Here is some code to load the starting dataframe if you'd like to play around:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [
        {'bloomberg': 'AAPL1', 'morningstar': 'AAPL2'},
        {'bloomberg': 'AAPL1', 'yahoo': 'AAPL3'},
        {'morningstar': 'GOOG4', 'yahoo': 'GOOG5'},
        {'bloomberg': 'GOOG6', 'morningstar': 'GOOG4'},
        {'bloomberg': 'IBM7', 'yahoo': 'IBM8'},
        {'morningstar': 'IBM9', 'yahoo': 'IBM8'},
        {'yahoo': 'FB'}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Chaining `ffill` and `bfill` will do what you want:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill', axis=1).fillna(method='bfill', axis=1).drop_duplicates()

  bloomberg morningstar yahoo
0      AAPL        AAPL  AAPL
2      GOOG        GOOG  GOOG
4       IBM         IBM   IBM
```

Comment: Shoot.  I didn't ask the right question.  Totally my bad as your answer definitely works for my example (thanks!).  That said, it's not working for my actual data because I have some data where there's only 1 row and that row contains missing data, which should remain missing, e.g. row [NaN, NaN, 'FB'] for columns ['bloomberg', 'morningstar', 'yahoo'], which is the only instance of FB in the data (i.e. the only FB row).  I don't know for sure that the 'bloomberg' value or 'morningstar' value for FB is 'FB'; so I need to leave those NaNs in the data.